# Renombrar archivos contenidos en varios directorios

Tags: linux

Necesito una ayuda para un script: tengo varios directorios con `pdf` en su interior. Los directorios siempre se llaman `001, 002…010, 011…`. Necesito meter todos los `pdf` en una misma carpeta. El problema es que el nombre de los archivos `pdf` se repite en cada una de las carpetas por lo que tendría que renombrarlos con su nombre original añadiéndole el sufijo por ejemplo `1, 2, 3 ….` para que vayan correlativos, es decir, el `fichero1` de la carpeta 001 iría antes que el `fichero1` de la carpeta 002

Solo he conseguido meter todos los `pdf` por orden en una sola carpeta, pero el problema es que sobrescribe los nombres:

```
find . -type f -name *.pdf -exec mv {} ./destino \;
```

Me falta el comando para renombrarlos ordenadamente

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: explicate mejor no e entendido nada de lo que quieres hacer como que va antes??

Comment: Las carpetas se llaman 001, 002, ... 010, etc y dentro de cada una hay archivos pdf numerados siempre de la misma manera: A001.pdf, A002.pdf. Necesito renombrar todos esos pdf ordenandolos por carpetas, es decir, primero irian todos los archivos pdf de la carpeta 001, a continuacion irian todos los archivos pdf de la carpeta 002, etc

Comment: ¿Qué terminal tienes bash?

Comment: Si la terminal de mi imac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xargs` siempre será la respuesta :)

```
$ find 00* -type f -name "*.pdf" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cp {} carpeta_total/$( tr "/" "_" <<< "{}")'
```

Lo que hago aquí es buscar en todos los directorios que comiencen con "00" (lo puedes adecuar al caso que quieras), archivos cuya terminación sea ".pdf", luego esos nombres los pasó a xargs que los utiliza como argumentos para pasar a un subproceso de bash. Este subproceso se encarga de copiar lo que haya en la ruta pasada, señalada por los caracteres "{}" a una carpeta llamada "carpeta_total" con un nombre que va a utilizar la misma ruta, salvo que en lugar de "/" va a cambiarlos por "_" (tu puedes eliminarlos, cambiar de caracter, etc).

Un ejemplo gráfico de esto sería corriendo el mismo comando salvo la instrucción en la subshell.

```
$ find 00* -type f -name "*.pdf" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo {} "->" carpeta_total/$( tr "/" "_" <<< "{}")'
001/001.pdf -> carpeta_total/001_001.pdf
001/002.pdf -> carpeta_total/001_002.pdf
002/001.pdf -> carpeta_total/002_001.pdf
002/002.pdf -> carpeta_total/002_002.pdf
003/001.pdf -> carpeta_total/003_001.pdf
003/002.pdf -> carpeta_total/003_002.pdf
004/001.pdf -> carpeta_total/004_001.pdf
004/002.pdf -> carpeta_total/004_002.pdf
005/001.pdf -> carpeta_total/005_001.pdf
005/002.pdf -> carpeta_total/005_002.pdf
```

Esto es únicamente para mostrar de dónde a dónde se van a mover los archivos.

La estructura que manejo es algo por este estilo:

```
$ tree
.
├── 001
│   ├── 001.pdf
│   ├── 002.pdf
├── 002
│   ├── 001.pdf
│   ├── 002.pdf
├── 003
│   ├── 001.pdf
│   ├── 002.pdf
├── 004
│   ├── 001.pdf
│   ├── 002.pdf
├── 005
│   ├── 001.pdf
│   ├── 002.pdf
└── carpeta_total
    ├── 001_001.pdf
    ├── 001_002.pdf
    ...
```

Donde "carpeta_total" es la carpeta que va a contener todos los archivos recopilados.

Comment: Fantastico, tema solucionado. Muchisimas gracias. Hacia tiempo que no programaba y estaba un poco obsoleto. No me dedico a la programacion mi mucho menos y solo vi unix en la universidad hace la tira de años cuando curse informatica. Encantado de haber escrito en este foro y lo agrego a mis favoritos

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo podrías resolver usando find y xargs sin problemas, según entiendo lo que estas pidiendo .

La idea es buscar los pdf e ir numerando con lo que tu comando podría quedar asi:

```
find . -type f -name *.pdf | awk 'BEGIN{ a=0 }{printf "cp \"%s\" ./destino/nro_%03d.pdf\n", $0, a++ }' | bash
```

Este comando debería copiar ( No le puse mv por las dudas ) , todos los archivos pdf a ./destino y a medida que los va encontrando los va a ir numerando en un archivo llamado nro_000.pdf , nro_001.pdf, y así sucesivamente.

Espero te sea de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la respuesta. Me da igual mv que cp. Con esto que me pasas ya me numera los archivos pero lo hace de manera desordenada. Las carpetas donde estan los pdf se llaman 001, 002... 010 etc. Y los archivos que estan en cada carpeta se llaman A001, A002... de tal manera que estos se repiten, pero necesito que esten ordenados, es decir, que el archivo A001.pdf de la carpeta 001 va antes que el archivo A001.pdf de la carpeta 002 y despues del archivo A002.pdf de la carpeta 001, no se si me explico. Necesito por tanto primero ordenar las carpetas y el unico comando que he encontrado que lo haga es ls -R pero nose combinarlo con lo que tu me has pasado